# Convert text to sentence case but with added constraints and grammar

Tags: c#, logic, artificial-intelligence, grammar

I have a task and i am lost in understanding how to begin. I have to convert a sentence that is always in capital case to sentence case. while that is easy and i have done it , there are some constraints.

for e.g. if there is a common short form like say VAT. this has to remain capital.
If there is something like City Tax, this has to remain as it is. similarly, for some other keywords.

Is there any ai approach I can take? performance is important here since this is for a backend API.

we have data to train if needed but it will require some manual labor. I would love if we could take a logical approach to it as well.
I code in C#.

I would love advice on how to approach this problem :)

Comment: Is it english, only? Or planned to be extended to other languages, too? What about mixed text (e.g. english sentence, but I throw in a german word)? Does it need to be 100% automatic from the get-go?

Comment: No need for AI here as it won't be any more "correct" than just storing the potential "common short forms" in a list and simply ignoring those words in the conversion.

Comment: @Fildor sometimes some things like hotels may have french names or some other languages.but the functionality is for English. although other languages might be part of this

Comment: @KrystianBorysewicz i am Coverting using regex. That poses one problem, say if the sentence doesn't have a space after a period. It will not work. We are dealing with a 3rd party API call and we do not have control on grammar.

Comment: If you really need this to be stable _and_ mostly correct _and_ fast, I'd recommend looking for some software that does text processing ( incl. grammatical / syntax / semantical analysis). There is a lot you can miss and do wrong and you won't be able to put your finger on it. Modern text analyzers, though, are amazing. I've seen systems deal with syntax mishaps (e.g. missing "." and adding it by analyzing the context), typos, ... won't be cheap, though.

Comment: @Fildor i will look out for them and come back and comment

Comment: @Fildor i couldnt find any code based analyzers. all seem to be online use. how will integrate them with my API